# Eclipse keeps re-checking my git repositories. How do I turn this off or change the interval?

Tags: eclipse, git

Whenever a long-running process in Eclipse (such as cleaning + rebuilding a large project), I see new processes such as "Updating git status for repository foo" pop up, waiting for my long-running process to finish.

Example:
[image]

I would like to turn off these updates, since I use a different app for managing my git repositories. I would also like to know how to change the frequency of these updates, if they are indeed being run at regular intervals.

I tried searching "git" in the Preferences, but didn't find any obvious culprits. I unchecked three options that looked like they *might* be related, but the updates still occur. The options I unchecked are:

- Team > Git > Projects > Automatically share projects located in a Git
  repository
- Team > Git > Projects > Track each branch's imported
  projects and restore on checkout
- Team > Git > Synchronize > Always
  launch fetch before synchronization

Comment: This allows Eclipse to automatically pick up changes in the git repository introduced by your different app without having you to manually refresh the Eclipse cache of the file system.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen If that's the case, shouldn't it only refresh when my other app (GitExtensions, git bash) does something?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try right clicking your project, and choose team > disconnect

Comment: Simple, effective. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. As a note, I was afraid that this would disable or delete my git setup in the filesystem, but as far as I can tell this didn't happen, so I can still manage them externally. Also, it seemed to disconnect all of my projects in CCS, but they're all from the same organization so that might have to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Found it. It's in:</s>

Team > Git, not any of Team > Git > [sub-category]

Uncheck "Refresh resources when index changes" under "Automatic Refresh" to disable the refreshes.

It doesn't seem to be run on a regular interval, but rather based on file changes.

Even after disabling these options, eclipse keeps updating my repos. This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you restart Eclipse after changing the setting?

Comment: @keks Yes. I shut down my desktop at the end of each workday, and I checked back days after my original answer post; eclipse was still doing it.